# Issue with AppDynamics REST call with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, appdynamics

I tried to call AppDynamics API using python requests but face an issue.
I wrote a sample code using the python client as follows...

```
from appd.request import AppDynamicsClient
c = AppDynamicsClient('URL','group','appd@123')
for app in c.get_applications():
    print app.id, app.name
```

It works fine.

But if I do a simple call like the following

```
import requests
usr =<uid>
pwd =<pwd>
url ='http://10.201.51.40:8090/controller/rest/applications?output=JSON'
response = requests.get(url,auth=(usr,pwd))
print 'response',response
```

I get the following response:

```
response <Response [401]>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

I think the general URL format for app dynamics applications are (notice the '#'):

```
url ='http://10.201.51.40:8090/controller/#/rest/applications?output=JSON'
```

Also, I think the requests.get method needs an additional parameter for the 'account'. For instance, my auth format looks like:

```
auth = (_username + '@' + _account, _password)
```

I am able to get a right response code back with this config. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

**You could also use native python code for more control:**

example:

```
import os
import sys
import urllib2
import base64

# if you have a proxy else comment out this line
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'proxy:port'}) 

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

username = "YOUR APPD REST API USER NAME"
password = "YOUR APPD REST API PASSWORD"

#Enter your request
request = urllib2.Request("https://yourappdendpoint/controller/rest/applications/141/events?time-range-type=BEFORE_NOW&duration-in-mins=5&event-types=ERROR,APPLICATION_ERROR,DIAGNOSTIC_SESSION&severities=ERROR")

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

html = response.read()
```

## This will get you the response and you can parse the XML as needed.

If you prefer it in JSON simply specify it in the request.